# Poetry package `ImportError` even though package is already present

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-poetry, asdf-vm

I'm using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) for dependency management. I have `poetry.lock` file in my repository & I used it to install the dependencies using `poetry install`. It created a virtualenv and is activated.

```sh
# poetry env list
python-tricks-sYsxS0XS-py3.7 (Activated)
```

When I try to add `numpy` as a dependency, it gives `ValueError: Package numpy is already present`. However, when I try to import the numpy package in a shell or run a script containing numpy in it's import statements, it throws `ModuleNotFoundError`.

What I don't understand is, if the package is already present then why is it throwing `ModuleNotFoundError`?

**Summary**

```sh
poetry install -> Installs dependencies & created a virtualenv 

poetry env list -> Sanity check: python-tricks-sYsxS0XS-py3.7 (Activated)

poetry add numpy -> [ValueError]: Package numpy is already present

poetry scripty.py -> script.py imports numpy gives ModuleNotFoundError
```

Can someone provide an explanation for this behaviour and possible solution?

Note:- I have installed python using [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/)

Comment: Which version of poetry do you use?

Comment: version - 1.0.10

Comment: can you also include the `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` section from your pyproject.toml file in this post?

Comment: [tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7"
flake8 = "^3.8.3"
numpy = "^1.19.1"

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned I was using `asdf`. It has a plugin for poetry as well - https://github.com/crflynn/asdf-poetry

Using that solved the issue-

```sh
asdf plugin-add poetry
asdf install poetry # 1.0.10 is the latest
asdf local poetry 1.0.10
```

Poetry then works alright -

```py
poetry add numpy
```